# View layout doesn't refresh on orientation change in android

Tags: android, view, rotation, orientation, onconfigurationchanged

I'd like my VIEW layout to be adjusted on orientation change.

My Manifest is set up with: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` on the activity.

I have `res/layout-land`, `res/layout-port`.

I have `onConfigurationChanged` in my `Activity` (it get's called on rotation).

In my `Activity` I have a `ViewFlipper` and inside it I have `LinearLayouts`.

When I START the `Activity` in port or land mode, the View's layout is correct (according
to my `res/layout-????` files).

But when I'm already in the `Activity` and I rotate the phone, then my View layout is not changed. The screen is rotated, and the `onCreate` of the activity is not called, as it's supposed to be, the `onConfigurationChanged` is called in the `Activity`, but the screen is always redrawn with the `LinearLayout` that was loaded when the `Activity` started.

I have a feeling that I miss out something in the `onConfigurationChanged`, but don't know what. I guess I need to call some function on the `ViewFlipper` or on the `LinearLayout` that's inside. What functions should I call?

```
ViewFlipper flipper;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    flipper = new ViewFlipper(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(flipper);
    initLayout();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(flipper);
}

void initLayout() {
    MyView myview = createMyView(0);
    flipper.addView(myview, 0);
    myview = createMyView(1);
    flipper.addView(myview, 1);
    myview = createMyView(1);
    flipper.addView(myview, 1);
}
```

I tried to add `flipper = new ViewFlipper(getApplicationContext());` to `onConfigurationChanged()` but that made everything black after rotation. I guess I'll have to call initLayout, but that would recalculate everything (and that's exactly what I don't want to do, and that's why I'm trying to do it with `onConfigurationChanged`, as opposed to the android default "dropMyActivity & createANewActivity"

**SOLUTION:**
Previously I thought I can trigger the layout to be refreshed on rotation, but it seems I have to re-create the layout with the current context (after the orientation change)

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.category_flipper);
    ViewFlipper oldFlipper = viewFlipper;
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.categoryFlipper);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout(this, cardData[i]);
        viewFlipper.addView(cl);
    }
    cardData[viewIndex].restorePlayer();
    viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(viewIndex);
    oldFlipper.removeAllViews();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `flipper` is a reference to the view that was initially installed, that's what's causing the problem. You need to pass the resource ID of the layout you want, not the old view from before the phone was rotated. The content view will then be bound to the new resource. Maybe something like this (modulo my guess at your resource identifiers):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.flipper);
    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
}
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the good direction, but still have to find out how to fit it to my case I'll add some more code to the original question

Comment: @Flöcsy - I'm looking at initLayout, which contains work you say that you don't want to repeat, but it looks like it's just creating all the views again. This is exactly what you need to do to reset the display when the screen is rotated. If you are doing expensive calculations at the same time you create the views, and these really are independent of configuration, you can capture and re-use them as described [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html)

Comment: Ted, i think you're right. Although createMyView is the expensive work, but I get the idea now, and probably I'm doing much more then what I'm supposed to (for example I'm parsing a zip file to find images (to show on a ImageButton) and mp3 files (to play when the button is played).

Comment: You can keep references to the images by saving them as non-configuration data. Probably the same goes for the mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

put that in your android manifest. android:configChanges="orientation"

in that case just try this and set your layout...

```
    if (Intraday.this.getResources (). getConfiguration (). orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){ 


    }
    else if (Intraday.this.getResources (). getConfiguration (). orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {      


    }
```